# AngularJS Binding an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller I have this:

```
$scope.participants = [
    {
        name: "Alan",
        birthday: new Date("1991/01/21"),
        takePart: true,
    },
    {
        name: "Leandro",
        birthday: new Date("1991/01/21"),
        takePart: true,
    },
    {
        name: "Alejandro",
        birthday: new Date("1991/03/21"),
        takePart: true,
    }
]
```

And I'm showing them in my View doing this:

```
<select name="" id="">
    <option ng-repeat="p in participants">{{ p.name }}</option>
</select>
```

I want to show each one information in some place when I select one of them in the select html element. Is there a way to bind the object?

Comment: Look at ngOptions https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) on your select box, and give it a [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel). When the select is changed the model will hold the object represented by the selected item.

After that just use the model to display

```
<select ng-model="currentItem" 
        ng-options="participant.name for participant in participants">
</select>
<div>
  {{currentItem.name}}<br/>
  {{currentItem.birthday}}<br/>
  {{currentItem.takePart}} </div>
</div>
```

**Demo**

```js
var app = angular.module("test",[]);
app.controller("Test",function($scope){
  $scope.participants = [
    {
        name: "Alan",
        birthday: new Date("1991/01/21"),
        takePart: true,
    },
    {
        name: "Leandro",
        birthday: new Date("1991/01/21"),
        takePart: true,
    },
    {
        name: "Alejandro",
        birthday: new Date("1991/03/21"),
        takePart: true,
    }
  ];  
  $scope.currentItem = $scope.participants[0];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="Test">
  <select ng-model="currentItem" ng-options="participant.name for participant in participants">
      
  </select>
  <div>
    {{currentItem.name}}<br/>
    {{currentItem.birthday}}<br/>
    {{currentItem.takePart}} </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While `ng-options` is better, this is your way:

HTML:

```
    <select name="" ng-model="test" ng-change="hello()" id="">
    <option ng-repeat="p in participants">{{ p.name }}</option>
</select>
    <p>{{pt.name}} - {{pt.birthday}} - {{pt.takePart}}</p>
```

JS:

```
     $scope.participants = [
    {
        name: "Alan",
        birthday: new Date("1991/01/21"),
        takePart: true,
    },
    {
        name: "Leandro",
        birthday: new Date("1991/01/21"),
        takePart: true,
    },
    {
        name: "Alejandro",
        birthday: new Date("1991/03/21"),
        takePart: true,
    }
]
    $scope.test=$scope.participants[0].name;
    $scope.pt=$scope.participants[0];
    $scope.hello = function(){ 
        angular.forEach($scope.participants, function(item){
            if(item.name==$scope.test){
                $scope.pt = item;
            }
        })
    };
```

Fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sourabh_/HB7LU/13597/)
(Sorry for the variable names ;))